# Parsing a file by the IP address - bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I'm trying to configure a `MapR` cluster:

```
./configure.sh -C 10.60.63.6, 10.226.86.24, 10.144.64.75 -Z 10.226.86.24 -N mycluster —create-user
```

The IP addresses come from `/etc/hosts`:

```
    10.60.63.6      dgnode-1 dgnode-1.dg.local
    10.144.64.75    dgnode-2 dgnode-2.dg.local
    10.226.98.24    namenode namenode.dg.local
```

What I need is a `bash` script that parses that file to produce a command like the one above. I'm not very good at `bash`, how can I accomplish that? 
The pattern is like this:

```
/opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -C <all_nodes> -Z <namenode> -HS <namenode> -N MyCluster.
```

Here is an example of the `/etc/hosts`:
        root@ip-10-226-98-24:/opt/mapr/server# cat /etc/hosts
        127.0.0.1 localhost

```
    # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
    ::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
    fe00::0 ip6-localnet
    ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
    ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
    ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
    ff02::3 ip6-allhosts

    ## vagrant-hostmanager-start
    10.60.63.6  dgnode-1 dgnode-1.dg.local
    10.144.64.75    dgnode-2 dgnode-2.dg.local
    10.226.98.24    namenode namenode.dg.local
    ## vagrant-hostmanager-end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this awk:

```
awk '/## vagrant-hostmanager-start/{
     a=1;
     next
  }
  /## vagrant-hostmanager-end/{
     exit
  }
  !a{
    next
  }
  a==1{
     a++;
     ips=$1;
     next
  }
  a>1{
     ips=ips ", " $1
  }
  $2=="namenode"{
     nn=$1
  } 
  END {
    printf "/opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -C %s -Z %s -HS %s -N MyCluster\n",
            ips, nn, nn
  }' /etc/hosts
```

> `/opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -C 10.60.63.6, 10.144.64.75, 10.226.98.24 -Z 10.226.98.24 -HS 10.226.98.24 -N MyCluster`

Comment: after that I would like to execute that command ... how do I do it?

Comment: I didn't work well: `root@ip-10-226-98-24:/opt/mapr/server# awk 'NR==1{ips=$1} NR>1{ips=ips ", " $1} $2=="namenode"{nn=$1} END{printf "/opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -C %s -Z %s -HS %s -N MyCluster\n", ips, nn, nn}' /etc/hosts
/opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -C 127.0.0.1, , #, ::1, fe00::0, ff00::0, ff02::1, ff02::2, ff02::3, , ##, 10.60.63.6, 10.144.64.75, 10.226.98.24, ##,  -Z 10.226.98.24 -HS 10.226.98.24 -N MyCluster`

Comment: This works with your original hosts file that has lines between `## vagrant-hostmanager-start` and `## vagrant-hostmanager-end` blocks.

Comment: Check my updated answer now for the new hosts file shown in question.